# incomplete type error in network device driver

Tags: c, kernel-module

I am building a simple network driver, following a tutorial, however even though net_device struct definition is said to be in `#include <linux.netdevice.h>` header file, I am getting a incomplete type error, the code is just basic `init_module` function which registers the device using `register_netdev()` call, and `cleanup_module`, I have a device init function for the `net_device` struct, in the tutorial the author uses `gcc` to build instead of a `Makefile`, `cc -I/usr/src/linux-2.4/include/ -Wall -c rtl8139.c`, can someone please point out where the definition of net_device lies if not in `linux/netdevice.h` and the proper way to build network device drivers
(working with ubuntu in virtual box btw)

```
#define MODULE             
#define __KERNEL__   

#include < linux/module.h >  
#include < linux/config.h >  

#include < linux/netdevice.h > 

int rtl8139_open (struct net_device *dev)
{
    printk("rtl8139_open called\n");
    netif_start_queue (dev);
    return 0;
}

int rtl8139_release (struct net_device *dev)
{
    printk ("rtl8139_release called\n");
    netif_stop_queue(dev);
    return 0;
}

static int rtl8139_xmit (struct sk_buff *skb, 
                struct net_device *dev)
{
    printk ("dummy xmit function called....\n");
    dev_kfree_skb(skb);
    return 0;
}

int rtl8139_init (struct net_device *dev)
{
    dev->open = rtl8139_open;
    dev->stop = rtl8139_release;
    dev->hard_start_xmit = rtl8139_xmit;
    printk ("8139 device initialized\n");
    return 0;
}

struct net_device rtl8139 = {init: rtl8139_init};

int rtl8139_init_module (void)
{
    int result;

    strcpy (rtl8139.name, "rtl8139");
    if ((result = register_netdev (&rtl8139))) {
        printk ("rtl8139: Error %d  initializing card rtl8139 card",result);
        return result;
    }
return 0;
}

void rtl8139_cleanup (void)
{
    printk ("<0> Cleaning Up the Module\n");
    unregister_netdev (&rtl8139);
    return;
}

module_init (rtl8139_init_module);
module_exit (rtl8139_cleanup);
```

here is the Makefile

```
obj-m += hello-1.o
obj-m += hello-2.o

all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: Rather than describing your code, please post your code, preferably as a [mre].

Comment: Please, post the **exact error message**. "proper way to build network device drivers" - Proper way for building kernel module is using KBuild system and makefiles. Calling `gcc` directly for building kernel module is almost always wrong.

Comment: I have also tried using a make file , but the same error persists, the Makefile is the basic Makefile for compiling kernel modules

Comment: Are you trying to build modern code for Linux kernel v2.4?!

Comment: No , this is just for experimental purposes I am aware that v2.4 is outdated, my kernel version is in the 5.0s, but I am confused about the incomplete type error for struct net_device which is defined in linux/netdevice.h